# Nginx proxy for AWS S3 v4 authentication issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-s3

Using https://github.com/anomalizer/ngx_aws_auth module I am trying to setup Nginx as a proxy for S3 bucket. Unfortunately I am getting instead:

```
<Error>
<Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
<Message>
The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you     provided. Check your key and signing method.
</Message>
<AWSAccessKeyId>AKIxxxx</AWSAccessKeyId>
<StringToSign>
AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Wed, 30-Jan-19 16:10:47 GMT 20190130/eu-west-1    /s3/aws4_request     d7e6xxxx
</StringToSign>
<SignatureProvided>
1647xxxx
</SignatureProvided>
```

My Nginx config:

```
worker_processes 1;
events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
  server {
    listen 80;
    client_max_body_size 100G;
    aws_access_key "AKIAxxxx";
    aws_signing_key "489OW0/xxxx=";
    aws_key_scope "20190130/eu-west-1/s3/aws4_request";
    aws_s3_bucket "bucket_name";
    location / {
      aws_sign;
      proxy_set_header x-amz-cf-id "";
      proxy_pass http://bucket_name.s3.amazonaws.com;
      proxy_set_header Host "bucket_name.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com";
      set_by_lua $now "return ngx.cookie_time(ngx.time())";
      proxy_set_header x-amz-date $now;
      proxy_hide_header "x-amz-id-2";
      proxy_hide_header "x-amz-request-id";
      resolver 8.8.8.8 valid=300s;
      resolver_timeout 10s;
    }
}
}
```

Signing key has been generated using generate_signing_key python script attached to the repo. Any idea what is wrong here?

Comment: imho the string to sign should definitely look somehow differrent (different date format, no spaces, ...)

Comment: @gusto2 is correct, the date in the string to sign [is wrong](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-header-based-auth.html) which suggests that the generated request's `x-amz-date` is also wrong -- it should be in iso8601, not w3c, format.  But also... looking at how this implementation works, it seems completely non-viable/unsustainable, requiring you to refresh the signing key in the nginx configuration once a week, or more.  The author seems to have solved the wrong problem and introduced unneeded complexity by making some of these design choices.

Comment: Why are you using "proxy_set_header x-amz-date $now;". The module takes care of adding the "x-amz-date" header already. Can you try removing that line of configuration?